# How to access an object with no keys, only values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, set

```
var hasDuplicates = "eyes";
var noDuplicates = new Set(hasDuplicates); // {"e", "y", "s"}


console.log(Object.keys(noDuplicates));   // []
console.log(Object.values(noDuplicates)); // []
```

I basically want to access the 'e', 'y', and the 's' of the set called 'noDuplicates'.

```
var setToArray = [];
for (spot in noDuplicates) {
    setToArray.push(Object.keys(noDuplicates)[spot])
}
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation for [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)?

Comment: Every objects has "keys". A `Set` is a special object that stores its values internally. Use its API to access the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert a Set to array:

```js
var hasDuplicates = "eyes";
var noDuplicates = new Set(hasDuplicates); // {"e", "y", "s"}
var setToArray = [...noDuplicates];

console.log(setToArray);
```

You can also use [`Set.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) or a [for...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to access the Set's values directly:

```js
var hasDuplicates = "eyes";
var noDuplicates = new Set(hasDuplicates); // {"e", "y", "s"}

noDuplicates.forEach(v => console.log(v));

for(const v of noDuplicates) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Thanks!

Comment: noDuplicates.forEach(v => console.log(v));

If I understand this correctly, you created a null function named v that prints out the e, y, and s once each where v acts as the iterator/index

Answer (score 0):

`noDuplicates` is a Set which provides an iterator. Simply use `for...of` or the spread operator `[... noDuplicates]` instead of `for...in`. Better yet, convert your set into an array directly with `Array.from`:

```js
let setToArray = Array.from(new Set([1, 1, 1, 2, 2]));
console.log(setToArray);
```

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: @FelixKling The spread syntax is commonly known as the "spread operator" within the community. Usages of this term is ubiquitous: [Ref 1](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator), [Ref 2](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-spread), [Ref 3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-spread-operator/).

Comment: @FelixKling Too late for that debate.

Comment: I would say, let's at least try here at SO to instate good naming habits.

Comment: I believe that people who know better have the obligation to use the proper terminology, to not spread misconceptions further (no pun intended). All these references could be updated/corrected (unless previous such attempts have been shut down). In fact, the MDN documentation on this was updated at some point.